# How do I show busy window when button click in winform apps

Tags: c#, winforms, busyindicator

My main form has one button. When the button is clicked, I  populate a grid. Here is my button click routine

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkExcludeCallCust.Checked)
    {
        if (chkEnable.Checked)
            RangeExclude = 1;
        else
            RangeExclude = 0;
    }

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            Search();
        }
    }).Start();

}
```

A thread is called when the user clicks on the search button. From that thread I fetch data from the database and populate the grid.

So here is my search routine:

```
private void Search()
{
    DataSet ds = null;

    if (wfrm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        wfrm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            wfrm.Show();
            wfrm.Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        wfrm.Show();
        wfrm.Refresh();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            btnSearch.Enabled = false;
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        btnSearch.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (!PingTest())
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                MessageBox.Show("VPN disconnected. Please connect and try again.", "DebtorCallerAssistance");
                return;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            MessageBox.Show("VPN disconnected. Please connect and try again.", "DebtorCallerAssistance");
            return;
        }
    }

    if (chkExcludeCallCust.InvokeRequired)
    {
        chkExcludeCallCust.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            DataLayer.SetConnectionString(_country);
            ds = LoadData(dtfrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), dtto.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), (chkExcludeCallCust.Checked ? 1 : 0), txtSearch.Text, 1, Pager.PageSize, false);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        DataLayer.SetConnectionString(_country);
        ds = LoadData(dtfrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), dtto.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), (chkExcludeCallCust.Checked ? 1 : 0), txtSearch.Text, 1, Pager.PageSize, false);
    }

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0] != null)
        {
            dtExport = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }

    if (outlookGrid1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        outlookGrid1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            outlookGrid1.BindData(ds, "data");
            View = "BoundInvoices";
            DataGridViewCellEventArgs evt = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, -1);
            object sender = null;
            //outlookGrid1_CellClick(sender, evt);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        //outlookGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        outlookGrid1.BindData(ds, "data");
        View = "BoundInvoices";
        DataGridViewCellEventArgs evt = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, -1);
        object sender = null;
        //outlookGrid1_CellClick(sender, evt);
    }

    if (wfrm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        wfrm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            wfrm.Hide();
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        wfrm.Hide();
    }

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        btnSearch.Enabled = true;
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        btnSearch.Enabled = true;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

At form load, I instantiate a borderless windows like:

```
WaitForm wfrm = null;
public Feedback(string country)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    wfrm = new WaitForm();
}
```

I also set a  few more properties for this window like:

```
startposition = CenterScreen
showinicon=false
showintaskbar=false
formboderstyle=none
```

`WaitForm` is shown only the first time I click the search button  I am not able to understand why `WaitForm` is not shown if the search button is clicked a second time.

Another issue is that there is a `PictureBox` on  `WaitForm` which has been assigned an animated  GIF. The first time `WaitForm` is shown the animation is not playing. Why animation isn't the animation playing when I show the WinForm?

Please tell me what I need to change in code in order to show the `WaitForm` whenever I click on the search button. I'd also like to know how I can make the GIF in `WaitForm`'s `PictureBox` animate.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318607/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is total nonsense to start a thread and invoke everything back to the GUI thread.
And DoEvents is a indicator for code smell. Bundle your invokes as invokes create a large Overhead

Change your code to something like this:

```
   private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnSearch.Enabled = false;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        this.wfrm.Show();

        Thread t = new Thread(this.Search);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Search()
    {
        while (isWorking)
        {
            DoHeavyWork();
            this.Invoke(new Action(ReportToWaitForm);
        }

        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.btnSearch.Enabled = true;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                this.wfrm.Hide();
            }));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help & code. when DoHeavyWork(); routine load data then animated gif stop playing the animation loaded in picbox on WaitForm. can u give me any idea which do not block animated gif to stop playing animation. plzz help.thanks

Comment: I guess you populate your Grid wrong.I cannot tell you what is keeping the GUI occupied. You can try to set the DataBinding before you Populate your Binding (Populating your Binding should be in the Background Thread).

Comment: r u trying to say to start another thread from Search() function to bind grid?

Comment: can u give minimum idea with sample code as a result i could accordingly change my search routine and that may stop freezing gif animation. thanks